# Weird performance difference when not caching uuid

Tags: elasticsearch

I read this [documentation article](https://www.elastic.co/blog/performance-considerations-elasticsearch-indexing) regarding Java UUIDs which says that using Java's random uuid is the worst choice.

I have a large amount of documents in one index where I have a Java random UUID in one of the fields, but not as the document id.

I'm running the following query which takes about 6000ms to return:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "and": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "events.d_id": "1175cbe1-5329-8463-7e7b-547aca5dbe83"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "events.a_id": "4495665825523018"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when setting `_cache` to `false` on that term, I'm getting results back in 4ms:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "and": [
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "events.d_id": "1175cbe1-5329-8463-7e7b-547aca5dbe83",
                            "_cache": false
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "term": {
                            "events.a_id": "4495665825523018"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I did another test where I changed the `events.d_id` to a non-existent value, but in the same format, the query would still take 6000ms and return 0 results. However when I changed the `-` to `_` the query took 4ms. It's like ES treats this specific format differently. Please note that the field is defined as `string` and `not_analyzed`